# No member named 'Blender' in namespace 'cv::detail' stitching.hpp error when using Simple Blob Detector

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I am trying to use the Simple Blog Detector with Swift and an OpenCV Objective C++ wrapper and OpenCV 3.1.0 for iOS. However, I am getting several errors. I do not understand them as they imply that I am using stitching.hpp, but I am not. Any suggestions? I cannot figure out why it would be calling the stitching.hpp blenders and exposure compensate.

The errors are: No member named 'ExposureCompensator' in namespace 'cv::detail' stitching.hpp and: No member named 'Blender' in namespace 'cv::detail' stitching.hpp

Headers were added to the beginning as I was originally getting Parse Issues from the Expected Identifier ‘NO’ in the macro. By adding these headers, I removed the Parse Issues as recommended in the source files, but this resulted in the new errors as described above.

```
#ifndef OPENCV_STITCHING_BLENDERS_HPP
#define OPENCV_STITCHING_BLENDERS_HPP

#if defined(NO)
#warning Detected Apple 'NO' macro definition, it can cause build conflicts. Please, include this header before any Apple headers.
#endif

#ifndef OPENCV_STITCHING_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATE_HPP
#define OPENCV_STITCHING_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATE_HPP

#if defined(NO)
#warning Detected Apple 'NO' macro definition, it can cause build conflicts. Please, include this header before any Apple headers.
#endif

#import "OpenWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

@implementation OpenWrapper

+(UIImage *) makeGrayscale:(UIImage *)myImage{

//  Convert UIImage to Mat
Mat imageMat;
UIImageToMat(myImage, imageMat);

//  Convert from color to grayscale image
Mat graymat;
cvtColor(imageMat, graymat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

//  Set up Simple Blob Parameters
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 200;
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 1500;
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minConvexity = 0.87;
params.filterByInertia = true;
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01;


//  Creat dectector with keypoints
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);

detector->detect(graymat, keypoints);

//  Mat im_with_keypoints;
Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints(graymat, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

//  Show blobs
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints );
waitKey(0);

//  Output results as UIIMage
return MatToUIImage(graymat);

}

#endif
#endif

@end
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple beginner mistake.  OpenCV documentation clearly states to put all OpenCV statements PRIOR to any Apple code to prevent an enum error.  What is meant is to make sure to put the opencv import statements before the Obj C++ import header statement.